# Change Audio Codec for Bluetooth Device

Tags: sound, bluetooth, codecs

I'm running Maverick Meerkat, and I have a Aliph Jawbone ERA for VoIP communications. I am using it to stream Pandora for some musical goodness while I work, and the sound quality is just awful. Is there a way to select/change/update the audio codec used to stream the signal to the headset for better sound quality?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For high quality streaming the codec used needs to be set to **A2DP**. This can be done in pulseaudio audio settings by choosing the appropriate (A2DP) profile in the *Hardware* tab.

If your sound quality is still poor then unfortunately the SBC codec (that is included as a fallback for low bandwith in the A2DP profile) may be used. You may want to test if in your individual settings this is improved when running the most recent [Bluez package](http://www.bluez.org/) (however you would need to compile this from source). Some debugging of the A2DP codec has been done there recently.

Comment: Can confirm, adjusting the SBC codec improves the quality a lot! Is there a way to choose another default value for SBC? My headset works great with "SBC XQ 552kbps" but the default is always just "SBC"